# How to get the path to a Nancy Razor view inside a view?

Tags: razor, nancy

I am trying to write an extension method which will be used inside a razor view to get the file path to said view.

I have tried putting the extension method on `HtmlHelpers<T>` and `NancyRazorViewBase` but cannot seem to get the correct information from the view or from the render context e.g.

```
public static string GetPath(this NancyRazorViewBase view)
{
    //Is null, expecting something like C:\app\views\index.cshtml
    return view.Path;
}

<input type="hidden" value="@this.GetPath()"/>
```

Is it possible to get the path to the current view from inside the view?

I am using Nancy 0.23.

Comment: I'm very curious as to why you want this, unfortunately I don't have an answer for you. Maybe try to have the Module set the path in a model or the ViewBag?

Comment: I require for special debugging purposes. Not sure that I can attach it to the ViewBag as wouldn't that require me to assign it in every route handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had overlooked the properties on `NegotiationContext` e.g. `view.RenderContext.Context.NegotiationContext.ViewName`.